# Ruby - nokogiri, open-uri - Fail to parse page

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, screen-scraping, open-uri

This code work on some pages, like klix.ba, but cant figure out why it doesn't work for others.

There is no error to explain what went wrong, nothing.

If puts page works, which means I can target the page, and parse it, why I cant get single elements?

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'


url = 'http://www.olx.ba/'

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7"


page = Nokogiri::XML(open(url,'User-Agent' => user_agent), nil, "UTF-8")

#puts page - This line work

puts page.xpath('a')
```

Comment: You are parsing from XML, why don't you parse the HTML `Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need a better idea of the problem. What have you tried when debugging? What sites work, and what don't?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what else to write. It was strange problem without any error messages, as I mentioned above. Works just fine on one page, but fails on another.Then @Phil M mention that calling XML probably causing the problem, and he was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why are you parsing it as XML?
The following should be correct, considering your page is a HTML website:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url,'User-Agent' => user_agent), nil, "UTF-8")
```

Furthermore, if you want to strip out all the links (`a`-tags), this is how:

```
page.css('a').each do |element|
   puts element
end
```

Comment: That `each` block won't strip out links. It only iterates over them and prints them. You should change the wording or add the code to actually strip them. But, why even mention it as that wasn't part of the question.

Comment: Hi. I understood the OP's as if that he wants to get all the a-tags of a certain website (`puts page.xpath('a')`). Now that's why I showed how to address an a-tag through css (`page.css('a')`) which will give him all a-elements. To output said element (Yes, the entire element as in `<a href="foo.html">Bar</a>`) I used the `.each` loop. Hope that solves the questions :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are want to parse content from a web page you need to do this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'


url = 'http://www.olx.ba/'

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7"


page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url,'User-Agent' => user_agent), nil, "UTF-8")

#puts page - This line work

puts page.xpath('a')
```

Here take a look at the [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html#from_the_internets) documentation

One thing I would suggest is to use a debugger break point in your code (probably after assigning `page`). Look at the [Pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) gem.

So I would do something like this:

```
 require 'nokogiri'
 require 'open-uri'
 require 'pry' # require the necessary library


    url = 'http://www.olx.ba/'

    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7"


    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url,'User-Agent' => user_agent), nil, "UTF-8")
    binding.pry # stop a moment in time in you code (break point)

    #puts page - This line work

    puts page.xpath('a')
```